# Faster way to compute the Sum of this function below?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have this problem I'm curious about where I have an Array and I need to compute the Sum of this function:

`Arr[L] + (Arr[L] ^ Arr[L+1]) + ... + (Arr[L] ^ Arr[L+1] ^ ... ^ Arr[R])`

**Example:**

If the Array given was: `[1, 2, 3, 5]` and I asked what's the sum on the range `[L = 1, R = 3]` (assuming 1-based Index), then it'd be:

`Sum = 1 + (1 ^ 2) + (1 ^ 2 ^ 3) = 4`

In this problem, the Array, the size of the Array, and the Ranges are given. My approach for this is too slow.

There's also a variable called Q which indicates the number of Queries that would process each [L, R].

**What I have:**

I XOR'ed each element and then summed it to a variable within the range of [L, R]. Is there any faster way to compute this if the elements in the Array are suppose... 1e18 or 1e26 larger?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main (int argc, const char** argv)
{
    long long int N, L, R;
    std::cin >> N;
    
    long long int Arr[N];
    for (long long int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> Arr[i];
    }

    std::cin >> L >> R;
        
    long long int Summation = 0, Answer = 0;    
    for (long long int i = L; i <= R; i++)
    {
        Answer = Answer ^ Arr[i - 1];
        Summation += Answer;
    }
        
    std::cout << Summation << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If Arr[L] is 2 , should your Sum be `2 + (2^3) + (2 ^ 3 ^ 5) = 7 ` rather than `1 + (2 ^ 3) + (2 ^ 3 ^ 5)` ?

Comment: No, because it's 1-based index.

Comment: So it should be `1 + (1 ^ 2) + (1 ^ 2 ^ 3) = 4`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, sorry I mistyped! I have corrected it.

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ or even https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the type of `Arr`?

Comment: One-dimensional.

Comment: Are these integers? Can they be negative?

Comment: Non-negative Integers.

Comment: I added what you wanted me to add @JaMiT

Comment: Well, you [could](https://godbolt.org/z/M65MMTq1z) drop *one* iteration ;). More seriously, the input loop is probably way more expansive than the second loop.

Comment: Do you have several queries (`L`, `R`) by `Arr`?

Comment: Are the values in the array random or is there a pattern (the posted example *has* one)? Is this part of a bigger problem?

Comment: I'll look to find another way to input them in, I guess. Yes, there are several queries of [L, R]. No, the Array values can be anything.

Comment: Please add the *"Yes, there are several queries of [L, R]"* part to the question. I suspect it's a key information to optimize the algorithm (not the single loop in the posted snippet, but the overall solution).

Comment: For example, imagine to overwrite the "array" with the running total of the sum (the value of `Summation` at each `i`), then, to process each query, you just have to evaluate `Sum[R] - Sum[L]` (probably plus 1).

Comment: I know it's not directly related to the question, but `long long int Arr[N];` is a variable length array (`N` is not a compile-time constant), so this is not standard C++. I suggest you use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Currently, the complexity is `O(N * Q)` (`Sum((Rn-Ln)...)`). With some pre-processing, you should be able to answer to each query in `O(1)`, probably something like `O(N + Q)`.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer : NOT A FASTER SOLUTION !
Changing a bit the subject by making L and R valid indices of an integer matrix ( range [0, size) ), the following function is working for me:

```
size_t xor_rec(size_t* array, size_t size, size_t l, size_t r) {
    if (l < 0 || r >= size || l > r) {
        return 0; // error control
    }
    if (r > l + 1) {
        size_t prev_to_prev_sum = xor_rec(array, size, l, r - 2);
        size_t prev_sum = xor_rec(array, size, l, r - 1);
        return prev_sum + ((prev_sum - prev_to_prev_sum) ^ array[r]);
    }
    if (r == l + 1) {
        return array[r - 1] + (array[r - 1] ^ array[r]);
    }
    if (r == l) {
        return array[r];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: changed int for size_t.

Comment: Array given was: [1, 2, 3, 5] and Range was: [L = 1, R = 3]. What does your function return you as the answer? Just curious.

Comment: It is done for indices from 0 to size -1. So input l== 0 r== 2 and the answer is correct (4). I did some testing. If you dont want to change indexes, just pass to the call l-1 and r-1

Comment: I see, I will test this further.

Comment: This is a valid approach in parallel programming theory - splits the operation in two sub-operations. However, for it to succeed you need to partition `array` in non-overlapping parts. This doesn't, so it's slower. (and it doesn't use threads either, so it obviously also fails on the actual parallel part)

Comment: What does this give you: ```Array = [10, 2, 68, 21, 15, 865, 581, 5, 3, 6]``` on the Ranges ```[6, 8]```, ```[1, 5]```, and ```[1, 9]```? The answers are ```1456, 269, and 2225```.

Comment: Edit: I re wrote it as it was yesterday because the new function was not correct. It runs slow because of the overlapping computations. The results for your indexes, assuming they are ranged `[1, size]`, are `1446, 269, 2209`.

Comment: @carce-bo I suspect the 5, between 581 and 3, in OP's array, was actually a **15** (to match the answers).

Answer (score 2):

There are two loops in your code:

```
for (long long int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    std::cin >> Arr[i];
}

long long int Summation = 0, Answer = 0;    
for (long long int i = L; i <= R; i++)
{
    Answer = Answer ^ Arr[i - 1];
    Summation += Answer;
}
```

The second loop is smaller, and only does two operations (`^=` and `+`). These are native CPU instructions; this will be memory bound on the sequential access of `Arr[]`. You can't speed this up. You need all elements, and it doesn't get faster than a single sequential scan. The CPU prefetcher will hit maximum memory bandwidth.

However, the killer is the first loop. Parsing digits takes many, many more operations, and the range is even larger.

Comment: You can also merge the two loops, and you don't need the array `Arr[]`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: I'm going to assume that the input is from a file, piped to the process, and you need to store something. The inputs `L` and `R` are only available after `Arr[]` is read. Doing preprocessing on `Arr[]` is possible, but that would not make the second loop faster (still memory bound), so it would only make the first loop slower.

Comment: One could read the string data in from the stream (e.g. linewise) and delay the parsing of the numbers and do it only for those, for which it is needed in the end. As the numbers have a maximum digit length and N is known before the loop, one memory allocation could allocate all the lines and each line has the the same amount of reserved memory to not loose time for many dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @Sebastian: Similar problem. Storing all those lines takes more memory, and more operations per digit.  Just checking whitespace between inputs is likely going to take more than 2 instructions.

Comment: @MSalters Parsing the string into decimal digits could take some time. There are other Q&As how to input stdin much faster than cin does.

Answer (score 1):

If indices are 0 based.  That is L=0 implies the first element: Arr[0] is the first element in the array, then it's simply this:

```
int sum = 0;
int prev = 0;

for (int i = L; i <= R; i++)
{
    int current = (prev ^ Arr[i]);
    sum += current;
    prev = current;
}
```

If it's 1 based, where L=1 is really Arr[0], then it's a quick adjustment:

```
int sum = 0;
int prev = 0;

for (int i = L; i <= R; i++)
{
    int current = (prev ^ Arr[i-1]);
    sum += current;
    prev = current;
}
```

Comment: This is to slow.

Comment: @Dex The algorithm is O(n), you cannot get below it. The array is accessed only once and you have two arithmetic operations on int32. If you want to accelerate and you do not have additional information about the numbers in the array, you have to play with O2/O3 optimization, loop unrolling, SIMD vector intrinsics, multithreading, GPU acceleration.

Comment: It's and `O(N)` solution. Unless there was some predictive pattern to the elements in Arr, this is as good as it's going to get. Is this one of those l33t code problems?  Is there anything else about the data you didn't mention before.  (i.e. all prime numbers, pre-sorted, no possible duplicates), etc.... ?

Comment: Besides the information given, L and R can be as big as N and N can be 2e5.

Comment: @Dex Probably the slowest instruction is `cin <<`, search stackoverflow.com, how to accelerate it/replace it with faster alternatives. There are some answers about it.

Comment: This answer is a mere variant of the question itself, no added-value whatsoever.

Comment: My bad, just saw the OP's history. Your answer came prior to the question's code.